# How to convert jpeg to tiff using Android and OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV to convert an image from jpeg to tiff. It should be pretty straight forward but for some reason it always fails when using imencode:

```
    String filename = mCameraActivity.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/TEST.jpg";
    Mat jpeg = Imgcodecs.imread(filename);

    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".tiff", jpeg, matOfByte);
```

The jpeg definitely exists and I can use imread and imwrite without issue. If there's a better way instead of using OpenCV then I'm all ears.

Any tips would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

Error messages:

```
    20:30:28.544 3643-3968/moter.androidocr E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (code) in bool cv::imencode(const cv::String&, cv::InputArray, std::vector<unsigned char>&, const std::vector<int>&), file /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp, line 603
```

Comment: In what sense does it "fail"?

Comment: Error messages would be a good idea :) It's error code 215:  imgcodecs::imencode_11() caught cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:603: error: (-215) code in function bool

Comment: Looks like [this place](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.0.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp#L603). That would suggest the TIFF ImageEncoder in your build doesn't support encoding directly to a buffer ([which is a possibility](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.0.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp#L467)), and uses a temporary file. It fails on the write -- perhaps there's a problem creating that temporary file? I'm not familiar with Android dev, so not sure what you'd need to do to solve that.

Comment: Try providing WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions ?

Comment: Maybe that's the ticket, I'm definitely granting WRITE_EXTERNAL permissions but maybe not READ. I'll give it a go when I get home!

Comment: The plot thickens, I granted the additional permissions and there's no difference in the outcome. However, I noticed this in my linux terminal: Corrupt JPEG data: 9 extraneous bytes before marker 0xdb... I am capturing the image using camera2 api. Could this be the issue that OpenCV is complaining about? I have tested imread and imread and they both worked.